Is it normal to get some request timed out in traceroute for Valorant Singapore server?
Is it normal to get some request timed out in traceroute for Valorant Singapore server?
This is my traceroute result in Valorant Singapore server.
Tracing route to 151.106.248.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1 
  2     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.160.23.1 
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.160.6.9 
  4     2 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  10.160.6.41 
  5     2 ms     3 ms     1 ms  10.161.0.17 
  6     8 ms     7 ms     7 ms  10.161.191.57 
  7     7 ms     8 ms     7 ms  14.1.100.230 
  8    55 ms    55 ms    55 ms  14.1.100.77 
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *     


I get a similar result (but, of-course, quite a different path).  I don't play games, but https://gist.github.com/coldfire7/bd349ded6b3a075c10a1683e68f1649f is useful, and reading between the lines this could be an issue/limitation of the way the IP address is advertised - and it may not be reachable.  That said, I also tried from a VPN to Singapore with the same result.

It's normal to some extent, especially if it's a game server that is behind a strict firewall (DDoS filtering or something) – if regular 'ping' (ICMP Echo) packets can't get through a firewall at some point, then Windows 'tracert' probes (literally the same ICMP Echo) also won't be able to get through, and traceroute will be able to see nothing beyond that point.
A large part of interpreting tracert results involves comparing them to what was previously seen (i.e. what is "normal" for that specific destination, even if not necessarily "normal" in general terms).
